# NUnit Testing with Action and Lambda

Tags: c#, testing, lambda, nunit, action

I have been reading up on Actions and Lambda expressions on MSDN but there is still something I am missing. I have the following public class.

```
public class ExitChecker
{
    public Action EnvironmentExitAction { get; set; }

    public ExitChecker(string[] args)
    {
        if (string.Compare(args[0], "-help", true) == 0)
        {
            EnvironmentExitAction = () => Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have the following test class.

```
[TestFixture]
public class AVSRunnerConsoleAppTests
{
    [Test]
    public void TestConsoleAppWithHelpArg()
    {
        string[] args = new string[1] { "-help" };           
        ExitChecker exitchecker = new ExitChecker(args);

        bool exitZeroOccured = false;
        exitchecker.EnvironmentExitAction = () => exitZeroOccured = true;

        Assert.That(exitZeroOccured, Is.True);
    }
}
```

I am attempting to test the Environment.Exit without actually calling the Environment.Exit. All seems to compile and run just fine but I can't seem to change the exitZeroOccured in the Lambda expression to true. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never invoking `EnvironmentExitAction`. Change your code to this:

```
[Test]
public void TestConsoleAppWithHelpArg()
{
    string[] args = new string[1] { "-help" };
    ExitChecker exitchecker = new ExitChecker(args);

    bool exitZeroOccured = false;
    exitchecker.EnvironmentExitAction = () => exitZeroOccured = true;

    exitchecker.EnvironmentExitAction.Invoke();

    Assert.That(exitZeroOccured, Is.True);
}
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I missed that. Off to do some more reading then...thanks a bunch. I actually thought the Invoke took place in the Lambda expression itself.

Comment: Pff, don't worry... I do that all the time. Although, to be honest, your test isn't really doing anything. You're only testing that invoking `Action` works, which it obviously does because it's a .NET class. You're never calling your `Environment.Exit(0);` code as the entirety of the tested code resides in the test itself.

Comment: Ha! True. I have been experimenting with some different testing options. Environment.Exit(0) kills the test and it probably isn't something that should be tested anyway but I thought I would give it a try.